# IAM Roles Anywhere - rolesanywhere-credential-helper on IBM AIX

Tags: macos, go, cross-compiling, aix, cgo

I'm encountering a compile error while attempting to build the AWS RolesAnywhere Credential Helper for AIX on macOS. I'm hoping someone here might have some insights or suggestions on how to resolve it.

When I run the command:

`GOOS=aix GOARCH=ppc64 go build -o build/bin/aws_signing_helper main.go`

I get this error:

```
# github.com/aws/rolesanywhere-credential-helper/aws_signing_helper 

aws_signing_helper/pkcs11_signer.go:62:20: undefined: pkcs11.ObjectHandle aws_signing_helper/pkcs11_signer.go:69:19: undefined: pkcs11.ObjectHandle aws_signing_helper/pkcs11_signer.go:75:17: undefined: pkcs11.SlotInfo aws_signing_helper/pkcs11_signer.go:76:17: undefined: pkcs11.TokenInfo aws_signing_helper/pkcs11_signer.go:82:29: undefined: pkcs11.Ctx aws_signing_helper/pkcs11_signer.go:92:57: undefined: pkcs11.Ctx aws_signing_helper/pkcs11_signer.go:126:50: undefined: pkcs11.Ctx aws_signing_helper/pkcs11_signer.go:209:80: undefined: pkcs11.Attribute aws_signing_helper/pkcs11_signer.go:234:39: undefined: pkcs11.Ctx aws_signing_helper/pkcs11_signer.go:234:72: undefined: pkcs11.SessionHandle aws_signing_helper/pkcs11_signer.go:234:72: too many errors
```

But when I build it for native architecture it works. Can you give som tip ?

Thanks.

Comment: This project appears to use `github.com/miekg/pkcs11` which has a hefty amount of C code. I guess `undefined: pkcs11.ObjectHandle` signals that that package fails to build and is not found when you try to cross-compile the original project. Can you may be first verify that `github.com/miekg/pkcs11` cross-compiles successfully given your `GOOS/GOARCH` combo? Note that you'll have to have a C cross-compiler and probably also libs for your target platform installed in order for that to succeed.

Comment: Given the apparent complexity of your task, I think SO is unfit for attempting to solve it. Please consider posting to the `golang-nuts` mailing list instead; see [this](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki#the-go-community) for more info.